# Testing cocoon with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cocoon-gem

I have installed cocoon into my app and am trying to test it with Rspec.

In my app, users upload a task and can select which recipients they want to be informed when the task is complete.

This is my test:

```
feature 'User adds recipient to task' do
  let(:task) { create(:task) }
  let(:recipient) { create(:recipient, task: task) }

  before do
    sign_in
  end

  scenario 'when there are two recipients' do
    visit new_task_path

    fill_in "Title", with: "test audio"

    click_on 'Add Recipient'

    fill_in 'Name', with: recipient.name

    fill_in 'Email', with: recipient.email
```

This is the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@task) do |f| %>
 <%= f.error_notification %>
 <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

<div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div id="recipients">
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :recipients do |recipient| %>
    <%= render "recipient_fields", f: recipient %>
 <% end %>
```

```
<div class="links">
 <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Recipient', f, :recipients %>
</div>

<div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit %>
  <%= link_to 'Back', :back, class: 'secondary-button' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Here is the recipients_fields that gets rendered:

```
<div class='nested-fields'>
<%= f.input :name, label: "Name" %>
<%= f.input :email %>
<%= link_to_remove_association "Remove Recipient", f %>
</div>
```

The error I am getting is:

```
User adds recipient to task when there are two recipients
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content 'Name'
```

I think it is because when I am saying 'click_on 'Add recipient' in my test. The fields are not being rendered - but they are in the browser.

Comment: Which engine are you using to test (phantom/selenium) and do you have javascript enabled for the feature?

Comment: You genius! I didn't have Javascript enabled.  Thanks!

Comment: @Koko May be you should add it as the answer :-)